# Is wearing a tie haram?

Tags: halal-haram, clothing

Is wearing a tie haram?

If yes, please give an answer with references. Someone told me that it is halal but I don't believe that because Muslim can't follow the Christians.

So I need reference to give him proof.

Answer (score 0):

Tie is not sign of Christian dress. So you can wear it. And it is not haram.